# Chrome profiling - how to narrow down what happened?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

**Scenario**

I'm making custom additions to a wordpress plugin (tagdivcomposer). When using the tagDiv Composer I can click on an element and an inspection panel display on the left hand side of the page. There must be an event dispatched / some code that is running to display the panel.

**Question**

Using the Chrome Developer Tools, how can I see exactly what code ran after clicking on an element?

**Notes**

I have recorded (profiled) clicking on an element that results in the inspection window opening. I'm hoping to reverse engineer the situation so that I can find the event / code that is starting the process.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools - Profiling]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Performance profile is definitely one way to do it, but DevTools also has [Event Listener Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#event-listeners) which let you pause whenever an event listener fires. From there you can step through the code, one line at a time. In this case, you'd enable the **click** checkbox under the **Mouse** category, and then click on the text to trigger the event listener.

Comment: I'd never heard of that option until you mentioned it on a google devs video, it's actually pretty useful, and I have been using it a lot lately, and for this question i think this is definitely the best choice.

Comment: Thanks! FYI the video randomguy04 refers to is: https://youtu.be/Eyw_mwbABIQ?t=3m38s

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I "solved" my issue:

I set up a local test and profiled it to see exactly what was going on.

- click on the "Click Here" text and an event is dispatched
- the event is heard and the `#box` has the class `green` added

**Code**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>

window.onload = function() {

    var BOX_CLICK = "box click";
  
    document.getElementById("click-here").onclick = function() {
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event(BOX_CLICK));

        console.log("click", this);
    }

    window.addEventListener(BOX_CLICK, function() {
        console.log("listener", this);

        document.getElementById("box").classList.add("green");
    });
}

  </script>
  <style>
    #box {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background-color: black;
    }
    .green {
        background-color: green !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="click-here">Click Here</p>
    <div id="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Profiling**

[image: chrome profiling]

## Answer

You can see the item `dispatchEvent` which is when the event was dispatched. Below it you see `(anonymous)` which is where my `listener` code is triggered. Using this pattern we see that the stack moves downward chronologically and new processes are from left to right chronologically.

I'm not 100% on the color code nor could I find much help online.

Comment: Regarding the color coding, the top-level events are color-coded to match the **Summary** tab. Functions are color-coded according to their script. Each script is assigned a color. Every function is color-coded according to the script that it originates from. So if `foo()` and `bar()` are the same color, it means they come from the same script. This is mostly covered in [View main thread activity](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#main).